# calculate average per quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have different years data as below:

```
yearmonth value1 
---------  ------
2016/01     33
2016/02     22
2016/03     22
2016/04     22
2016/05     22
2016/06     25
2016/07     44
2016/08     44
2016/09     44
2016/10     66
2016/11     44
2016/12     34
```

I want to calculate average of `value1` per quarter.Quarters should be 
    considered as below:
`Quarter 1 = month 01 till month 03
Quarter 2 = month 01 till month 06
Quarter 3 = month 01 till month 09
Quarter 4 = month 01 till month 12`

I tried using over but it is not fetching correct data.

Comment: quarter should be 4 to 6 right?

Comment: Pls provide sample data to work with

Comment: No saravanath. It should be from jan to june for second quarter and so on.Sample data is provided in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table tab1;
create table tab1 (
    yearmonth char(7),
    val number
);
insert into tab1 values('2016/02', 12);
insert into tab1 values('2017/09', 10);
insert into tab1 values('2018/11', 8);
insert into tab1 values('2013/07', 6);
insert into tab1 values('2014/12', 5);
insert into tab1 values('2016/08', 25);
insert into tab1 values('2013/06', 6);
insert into tab1 values('2013/04', 6);


--version 1
select q, round(avg(val),4) as avg_val
from (
    select a.*,
    to_char(to_date(yearmonth, 'yyyy/MM'),'Q') as Q -- convert string to date and get Q
    from tab1 a
)
group by q
order by q

-- version 2
select 
avg(case when q <= 1 then val end) as q1_cum,
avg(case when q <= 2 then val end) as q2_cum,
avg(case when q <= 3 then val end) as q3_cum,
avg(case when q <= 4 then val end) as q4_cum
from (
    select a.*,
    to_number(to_char(to_date(yearmonth, 'yyyy/MM'),'Q')) as q -- convert string to date and get Q
    from tab1 a
) a
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz.But your version 2 query gives error as "Numeric value 'Q' is not recognized". Why is it so?Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server 2008 :

I did for 1 quarter you can try similar method :

```
create table calculation
(
 yearmonth varchar(200),
 value1 float
 );

  insert into calculation values('2016/01',33);
  insert into calculation values('2016/02',22);
  insert into calculation values('2016/03',22);
  insert into calculation values('2016/04',22);
  insert into calculation values('2016/05',22);
  insert into calculation values('2016/06',25);

  select
  avg(case when yearmonth between '2016/01' and '2016/03' then value1 end) as qtr1
  from calculation
```

Note:
Store the date in proper format

Comment: As I am new to sql I am not getting your logic of using "between". Can you show me how this can calculate for other quarters for all the years

Comment: Between 1 and 3 means it will take value of (1,2,3)

Answer (score 0):

I enclose SQL-Server version - previous one was an Oracle one: :)

```
create table tab1 (
    yearmonth varchar(7),
    val int
);
insert into tab1 values('2016/02', 12);
insert into tab1 values('2017/09', 10);
insert into tab1 values('2018/11', 8);
insert into tab1 values('2013/07', 6);
insert into tab1 values('2014/12', 5);
insert into tab1 values('2016/08', 25);
insert into tab1 values('2013/06', 6);
insert into tab1 values('2013/04', 6);

select 
avg(case when b.q <= 1 then val end) as q1_cum,
avg(case when b.q <= 2 then val end) as q2_cum,
avg(case when b.q <= 3 then val end) as q3_cum,
avg(case when b.q <= 4 then val end) as q4_cum
from (
    select a.*, 
    datepart(quarter,convert(date,(yearmonth + '/01'),120)) as q
    from tab1 a
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a day to your column `yearmonth` to be able to use `DATEPART` function.
And then you will have a possibility to get average `VALUE` by `PARTITIONs` of quarter:

```
SELECT 
  q.yearmonth
, q.QuarterPart
, AVG(q.val)  OVER (PARTITION BY q.QuarterPart ORDER BY q.QuarterPart) AvgByQuarter
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  t.yearmonth
, t.val
, DATEPART(QUARTER, concat(t.yearmonth, '/01')) QuarterPart
FROM @table t
)q
```

And sample data:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
    yearmonth VARCHAR(10),
    val int
);
insert into @table values('2016/01', 33);
insert into @table values('2016/02', 22);
insert into @table values('2016/03', 22);
insert into @table values('2016/04', 22);
insert into @table values('2016/05', 22);
insert into @table values('2016/06', 25);
insert into @table values('2016/07', 44);
insert into @table values('2016/08', 44);
insert into @table values('2016/09', 44);
insert into @table values('2016/10', 66);
insert into @table values('2016/11', 44);
insert into @table values('2016/12', 34);
```

OUTPUT:

```
yearmonth   val QuarterPart AvgByQuarter
2016/01     33      1           25
2016/02     22      1           25
2016/03     22      1           25
2016/04     22      2           23
2016/05     22      2           23
2016/06     25      2           23
2016/07     44      3           44
2016/08     44      3           44
2016/09     44      3           44
2016/10     66      4           48
2016/11     44      4           48
2016/12     34      4           48
```

Answer (score 0):

Amusing, you want *cumulative* quarters.  That makes this a bit tricky.  Anyway, I wouldn't use date arithmetic for this, because the source data is not dates.

```
select q, avg(value1)
from t cross apply
     (values ('q1'),
             (case when right(yearmonth, 2) > '03' then 'q2'  end),
             (case when right(yearmonth, 2) > '06' then 'q3' end),
             (case when right(yearmonth, 2) > '09' then 'q4' end)
     ) q
where q is not null
group by q;
```

Actually, I would also include the year, `left(yearmonth, 4)` in both the `select` and `group by`.

If you didn't want cumulative results, then:

```
select left(yearmonth, 4) as yyyy, q, 
       avg(value1)
from t cross apply
     (values (case when right(yearmonth, 2) <= '03' then 'q1'
                   when right(yearmonth, 2) <= '06' then 'q2'
                   when right(yearmonth, 2) <= '09' then 'q3'
                   else 'q4'
              end)
     ) q
where q is not null
group by eft(yearmonth, 4), q;
```

You could also get the cumulative average as well:

```
select left(yearmonth, 4) as yyyy, q, 
       avg(value1),
       (sum(sum(value1)) over (partition by left(yearmonth, 4) order by q) /
        sum(count(*)) over (partition by left(yearmonth, 4) order by q)
       ) as cumulative_average
```